# How safe would deep-sea investigation of a nuclear battleground be?

Tags: science-based, humans, underwater, radiation, safety

Jormungandr, the snakebot of doom, is no more.  Its remains are lying on the bottom of the sea in the Aleutian Trench to the south of the [Rat Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_Islands), where it was nuked to pieces by three hundred approximately half-megaton thermonuclear warheads, 288 of which were American [Trident II SLBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UGM-133_Trident_II) MIRVs, and 12 of which were Russian [Shkval torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VA-111_Shkval) nuclear warheads, plus six fifty-megaton Russian thermonuclear warheads, similar to the [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) test weapon, carried to the target by [Poseidon torpedoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status-6_Oceanic_Multipurpose_System).

However, considering the 5 to 7 kilometre depth of the water in which Jormungandr's remains lie, a civilian ship, the [*DSSV Pressure Drop*](https://fivedeeps.com/home/technology/vessel/) and the deep-submergence submarine [*DSV Limiting Factor*](https://fivedeeps.com/home/technology/sub/) have been brought in to sonar-map the sea floor, and send down investigators to visually verify Jormungandr's destruction.  However, considering all the nukes that were detonated in the area over the course of about a half-hour, the civilian crew is worried about radiation exposure, a mere six hours after the battle.  There has been a considerable underwater landslide, and the nukes have churned up the water even further.  Jormungandr's fusion reactors have all shut down or have been destroyed, but are still cooling, causing thermal water convection.

So, my question is: Just how safe is this place?  What is the likely risk to the crew of the *Pressure Drop* and to the crew of the *Limiting Factor* who actually go down to inspect Jormungandr's remains in the middle of this nuclear battlefield?

Comment: *Safe ?* For your version of Earth, large parts of the sea ecosystem may not have survived the operation. 300 nukes.. that's a lot of nukes !

Comment: A possible monkey wrench:  Underwater booms leave behind an ensonified zone--a gazillion tiny bubbles.  Underwater navigation is by sonar and these are opaque to sonar.  I know the ensonified zone from a nuke lasts a fair while but my memory is failing me on how long and I'm having no success with Google.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm aware of ensonified zones.  It's part of the reason why the investigation is 6+ hours after the battle.

Comment: @MontyWild I figured 6 hours was remarkably fast for ships even reaching ground zero.

Comment: Depending on what part of the nuke you're interested in, you could also look at thermobaric weapons, or even bunkerbusters and other piercing ordinance, for a much less enduring hazard.

Comment: Wouldn't such an operation be actually impossible to carry out? 30 minutes to detonate 300 nukes is 10 per minute, so one every 6 seconds. I don't know how long the explosions last(it probably differs by yield) but I imagine quite a lot longer than 6 seconds. That would interfere with other detonations I think.

Comment: Why so many bombs? No know science would be able to make something that can withstand a couple of those in a direct hit. Are 300 really needed?

Comment: Frame question; Did your escapade create a tsunami?

Comment: @EthanBolker Probably, but not a radioactive one except for the closest parts of the coastline. I’m not finding readily available info about the warheads used in the old Shkvals, but the rest of the arsenal, assuming W88s in the Trident IIs (the largest warhead currently available for them) and a typical ‘modern’ configuration, is ~847 Mt of nuclear warheads, equivalent to roughly 3.544e+18 Joules, or about _4.25 times the energy of the 1883 eruption of Krakatoa_.

Comment: @GensysLTD many of the detonations are timed and detonate effectively simultaneously.

Comment: 5-7 kilometers of sea pressure are nothing to sneeze at, that's quite dangerous. If you mean the radioactivity, that can be negated pretty much in entirety by putting a thick plastic bag around your sub and bringing a few meters thick bubble of clean water with you. If you can get multiple humans *that* deep and live to tell about it, the radiation is utterly child's play.

Comment: @MontyWild yeah, that makes more sense. The "all the nukes that were detonated in the area over the course of about a half-hour" suggests some kind of sustained bombing or something like this, hence my confusion :)

Comment: Two weeks. You can go outside after WWIII *for limited amounts of time*, two weeks later. One or a thousand, kilo tons or mega tons; specifics don't really matter.... **Two weeks.** - Six hours later, the maximum recommended exposure time is probably about half a second. The first three days are an absolute no-go.

Comment: @Mazura in two weeks, if Jormungandr isn't dead, it could be reaching Yokohama.  I figure that just standing off in its projected line of advance and listening for the noisy SoB should be sufficient.

Comment: @MontyWild - have fun timing that precisely. Nukes don't take nuclear detonations well. If you're not _very_ precise the radiation front from one hits the others before they finish detonating and they fizzle. It's possibly doable, especially with distance between the bombs, but it's nowhere near 'easy'. Picture 'research to develop a new warhead', not 'a few tweaks'. (That being said, it being that far underwater makes this easier in some ways. Water absorbs radiation quite well, all things considered.)

Comment: @TLW It's easier underwater, as you said.  On land, I'd be far more worried about warhead fratricide.

Comment: Additional frame challenge: Are you sure you want to use nukes against a mecha, rather than a destructive with less long-time consequences for lifeforms?

Comment: @EgorHans What else would you suggest be used? Jormungandr had 14 metres of tungsten-uranium armour.  It'd just ignore anything conventional.

Comment: Oh, if it's running on nuclear power anyway, I guess there's not much to lose.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### We already did this. And oh boy, what a mess.

The target wasn't a sea monster, but the Japanese battleship *Nagato*, Yamamoto's flagship at Pearl Harbor. And it wasn't any *Tsar Bomba*, just an ordinary run-of-the-mill 22-kiloton *Fat Man*, same as dropped on Nagasaki in WWII.

From *[Operation Crossroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossroads)*, the Baker* test specifically.  (they were pretty sore about having missed *Nagato* by a half mile due to sloppy bombardiering on the Able* test.

And, the fools detonated the "small" nuke *underwater*.

Here's the problem.  Atom bomb detonations emit lots of surplus high-energy neutrons. Air contains nitrogen, oxygen, hydrogen (via H<sub>2</sub>O) and argon. Hydrogen and oxygen don't capture fast neutrons at any rate. Some of these absorb neutrons (argon-41 has a 100 minute half life so doesn't last long;  nitrogen-15, oxygen-17 and hydrogen-2 are stable).  **But salt water contains sodium and chlorine**. Neutrons turn sodium into sodium-24 - a monstrous beast with a 15-hour half life, and short half-life means extremely intense radiation.

This.  This is why *you don't do in-seawater detonations*.

[image]

Now, you didn't detonate a Nagasaki bomb. You detonated about a million of those worth.   Well, OK, about 300 megatons, so about 13,000 Nagasaki bombs.  That is a lot of sodium-24.

### The survey crew is already dead.

Just from *even thinking about* going anywhere near that radioactive mega-soup only 6 hours later.

Honestly, they're probably already dead simply by being within 6 hours' sailing range of it.

Fortunately, half-life is exponential. The nastiest customer, sodium-24, is down to half in 15 hours, down to 1/4 in 30 hours, 1/8 in 45 hours and 1/16 in 60 hours. 120 hours is 1/256 (that's 5 days).  1/1024 happens in 150 hours (6.25 days).

Of course you detonated *13,000 times as much* - so you'll have that much more material created in the first place. Figure more like 2-1/2 weeks to safely enter the area.

The *Nagato* took damage, but nothing that threatened its watertightness.  The problem was, the radiation was so severe that it was impossible for crews to repair trivial leaks, so it sank in 5 days. The German cruiser *Prinz Eugen* sank the same way, though it took a few months (the contaminants were other elements).

---

---

---

* Able and Baker were simply the military phonetic codes for the letters A and B.  Now called Alpha and Bravo.

Comment: Ouch!  I'm really glad that you posted this.  While  I wonder how much of the fallout would make it to the surface after blasts several kilometers deep, I don't think that anyone will be going anywhere near this place for at least a month if they could possibly avoid it.  It looks like they'll have to verify Jormungandr's destruction some other way.

Comment: @MontyWild Yeah, that radiation would kill robotic unmanned DSRVs. It would kill anything HP Lovecraft has come up with.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica `It would kill anything HP Lovecraft has come up with` or, create something new HP Lovecraft couldn't even dream of... _enter Cthulludzilla_

Comment: A technical nitpick for an excellent answer: Sodium-24 is created by thermal neutron capture, not by a fast neutron process. H20, however, is fantastic at thermalizing fast neutrons.

Comment: One would think that if the seawater was flowing, most of the radiation would be swept away in not too long a time.  Also, water is actually a fairly good radiation shield.  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/what-thickness-depth-of-water-would-be-required-to-provide-radiation-shielding-i

Comment: Actually, it took 5 days for the Nagato to sink, thanks to the great compartmentalization of the ship. Baker took place on the morning of 25 July, and Nagato sank during the night of 29/30 July.

Comment: @MontyWild You could also see what happen during wigwam nuclear test, 610 m under water. The radiation at the surface wasn't that high, but again, the power was "only" 30 kt, orders of magnitude below what would happen with your arsenal

Comment: "This is why you don't ever do in-seawater detonations." -- and then they went and did it 4 more times...

Comment: It's more complicated than you make it sound.  Sodium-24 is ferociously radioactive, but water is a phenomenally good radiation shield.  As long as the crew carries a geiger counter and turns around once it starts making worrying noises, they'll be fine.

Answer (score 19):

Water is routinely used to store in a safe way radioactive materials like those present in a working nuclear reactor, like Randall Munroe tells in one of his [What it](https://what-if.xkcd.com/29/)

> Spent fuel from nuclear reactors is highly radioactive. Water is good for both radiation shielding and cooling, so fuel is stored at the bottom of pools for a couple decades until it’s inert enough to be moved into dry casks. We haven’t really agreed on where to put those dry casks yet. One of these days we should probably figure that out.

> For the kinds of radiation coming off spent nuclear fuel, every 7 centimeters of water cuts the amount of radiation in half.
> [image]
>
> Swimming to the bottom, touching your elbows to a fresh fuel canister, and immediately swimming back up would probably be enough to kill you.

> Yet outside the outer boundary, you could swim around as long as you wanted—the dose from the core would be less than the normal background dose you get walking around. In fact, as long as you were underwater, you would be shielded from most of that normal background dose. You may actually receive a lower dose of radiation treading water in a spent fuel pool than walking around on the street.

Based on the above, I don't think it's particularly dangerous, as long as the crew don't ingest water or other substance present in loco.

Considering that in your case the radioactive sources won't be concentrated in a single place but diluted in water, water which will be hot from the radiation and thus it will move up creating a circulation, the crew could simply pad the vessel with clean water to reduce the risks. A wall of water bottles give already more than the 7 cm mentioned above. Of course, since the problem lays in the cumulative dose, they better not slack down there.

Comment: Of course, as Mr. Munroe's source for that particular question so helpfully reminded him/us, you'd probably die well before you reach the spent fuel pool - from gunshot wounds.

Comment: When this happens in the open sea, there will be salt water. The salt will be affected by the radiation, the danger area indicated may become wider..  Sodium and Chlorine readily absorb neutrons especially sodium-23 and chlorine-35 atoms, which change to radioactive isotopes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_explosion

Comment: @Goodies Yes, but the water also shields them.  The danger is fallout.  The sub is in basically zero danger but the surface ship might have problems.

Comment: @LorenPechtel the use of nukes was *excessive* in this case. The sodium ions desolved **in** the sea water will have become radioactive. How would these divers protect themselves from that ? there will be fallout too, the area will be difficult to reach safely.

Comment: @Goodies What divers?  They're going way below human survival limits, it's a sub with manipulator arms.  Only the sodium very close to the hull is any threat at all.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Sodium-24 is a gamma emitter (2 photons, around 2MeV). That's not easily shielded. It's also a beta emitter, but that part is essentially harmless for the reasons you mention.

Comment: @MSalters The water itself is a pretty good shield--you'll only be getting the radiation from right near the sub and that will be attenuated by the hull--anything that can survive to those depths is very beefy and thus will be at least a moderate shield.  The Trieste had 5 inch walls and the half value for steel is about half an inch.  Thus only 3% makes it though the pressure hull.

Answer (score 10):

Frame challenge:

There is no reason to send people in the extremely confined vessels needed to survive such depths. Just send down a robot on a tether and even if it does get dangerously irradiated (as other answers have said, an unlikely proposition) it can just be cut free and join the rest of the debris.

Comment: Unfortunately, in 2017 when this story occurs, there are no robots which can survive the 5-7 km depth *and* perform the necessary observations.  Only a manned sub can do what is needed.  I already looked into that.

Comment: Sorry, making an ROV operate at such a depth is an engineering challenge, if there were reason to do it then it could be done. We don't currently have reason, these people do.

Comment: These people have mere hours to either verify that Jormungandr is dead, or to nuke it again before it reaches Yokohama.  That isn't enough time to build a robot.  The operation was only a few days in the planning.  They went with what was available.

Comment: @MontyWild deep sea rovers existed way back in 2009, and of course you always have a dual system, rovers tethered to a submarine. you are certainly not using divers at that depth.

Comment: @John, certainly they did... but the only 5000m+ depth capable remote robot available in 2017 didn't have the required capabilities.

Comment: @MontyWild you said all it has to do is visually verify , which the rover is more than capable of. what extra functions do you think a human occupied submarine will give you?

Comment: @John, a manned sub would have a manipulator.  Getting a sample - even if radioactive - would be additional confirmation.  The rover available at that time only had sediment sampling gear.

Comment: @MontyWild most definitely not true, the navy had salvage ROV in 2017 and NOAA had the huge deep discoverer with many types of manipulators. there is a huge diversity of rovers throughout the early 2000's including oil rig construction, archeology and salvage. again what do you think human subs can do rovers can't?

Comment: @John Can you please give me links to those?   ROVs would fit the story better, if any that were suitable existed.

Comment: here are four, 1. https://nautiluslive.org/tech/rov-hercules, 2. https://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/technology/subs/deep-discoverer/deep-discoverer.html, 3. https://www.navsea.navy.mil/Home/SUPSALV/00C2-Salvage/Remotely-Operated-Vehicles/, 4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZzZ6ZPkvT4 look at deep water oil rig rov for a lot of options.

Comment: @John, None of those ROVs are designed for operation below 6000m, and the Aleutian trench is 7500m at its deepest.  Even ROVs designed for 11000m have imploded at 9-10 km depth, so you can't just fudge it without a high risk of losing the ROV entirely.  Jormungandr's remains are 5-7000m down, but when the mission was designed, it wasn't known where or if it would be stopped.

Comment: @MontyWild your specifications were 5-7 which all of them can do, and the oil rig rovs can operate down to 7000m  and again those are not the only rov, there were thousands around at the time. here is a few for 7000m or more.  https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Development-of-7000m-work-class-ROV-%E2%80%9CKAIKO-Mk-IV%E2%80%9D-Nakajoh-Miyazaki/a69d78c9c98cadfd88275629b591e618dae29ff1

Comment: What is unsaid in this discussion is that, of course, it is entirely likely that the military and intelligence agencies of the world powers have resources that are not listed anywhere on the internet.  A deep sea ROV for imaging and even (partial) recovery of things like someone else's lost nuclear submarine in a deep trench is a reasonable extrapolation, especially given the history of these things.  Doubtful if they could be deployed in just 6 hours though. (See [Glomar Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glomar_Explorer) for just one example)

Comment: @MontyWild Can you expand on what you need your human crew to do at that depth, specifically? It's not as if human-crewed subs for that depth are extremely versatile - the humans can look out of tiny windows and operate binary (open/close, up/down, on/off) mechanisms on the ouside.

Answer (score 6):

Radioactivity decays to roughly 10% within 7 hours and 1% within 48 hours [https://www.britannica.com/technology/nuclear-weapon/Residual-radiation-and-fallout][1] but given the intensity of the bombardment substantial radioactivity would remain. That said the crew would be substantially protected.

The radioactive area would (presumably) have covered several square km of the seafloor to ensure a hit and due to targeting inaccuracy. After 6 hours thermal plumes would have spread the radioactive plume into a rising column and dispersed it sideways to a more limited extent. The resulting volume of contaminated sea water would be vast.

Water is very good at blocking radiation so only the tiny proportion of sea water within a few metres of the pressure vessel would present a hazard and that would be a very tiny proportion of the entire irradiated volume.

But even radiation coming from a few metres away would be greatly reduced. Alpha and beta radiation would be blocked entirely and the very thick pressure vessel would provide considerable protection from gamma radiation.

So not the sort of mission I would want to go on, but I suspect the crew would be ok. A bigger problem would be seeing anything as the fine sediment would turn the water above the sea floor into liquid mud that would take a very long time to settle.
[1]: https://www.britannica.com/technology/nuclear-weapon/Residual-radiation-and-fallout

Answer (score 5):

I once stood on the edge an what looked very much like a deeper than average swimming pool and looked down at the blue glow coming from some old fuel rods. It was a bit freaky, but the people who ran the reactor assured me it was safe, as long as I didn't jump in and swim too close to the rods.

Of course, spent fuel rods are probably a lot less radioactive than the remains of a heavily nuked nuclear powered giant robot. I'd recommend radiation meters on booms extending out the bottom, front, and sides of any crewed submersibles, since "too close" won't be very easy to define in a debris field like this.

Comment: I doubt that a Geiger counter could survive 5+ km depths...

Comment: @MontyWild - A normal one couldn't, but I've got a suspicion that the US and Russian navies might already have worked out how to put one together. If none can be made ready in time, initial passes for sonar mapping shouldn't require getting too close to the debris. If the snake bot is in small pieces, close up photography can wait. If there's a big enough surviving piece, then the submersible crews will have to take more serious risks.

Comment: @MontyWild deep water radiation counters are [definitely a thing](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Deep-water-scintillation-counter-to-estimate-in-Deineko-Eremeev/08f83c138c8215a252cfd93cf449cba57162300e).

Answer (score 5):

Frame Challenge:

> nuked to pieces by three hundred approximately half-megaton thermonuclear warheads

> visually verify Jormungandr's destruction

A single nuke will not destroy anything but literally vaporise it into nothingness. A hydrogen bomb even more so. If such a warhead goes off in close proximity to you, there are zero chances of survival/escape. You exist and in a split second you entire molecular structure is catastrophically obliterated.

As such: 300 nukes/h-bombs are ridiculous overkill and there is nothing that will remain. Perhaps little metal dust, sprinkled over the ocean floor, but nothing to be visually verified.

Comment: I think you may be overstating nuclear firepower a little here. (A sentence I never thought I'd say, it's usually the other way around). Jormungandr is massive enough and armoured sufficiently I'd expect that even 150mt of nuclear blasts wouldn't completely destroy it. There will definitely be large chunks of armour left afterwards from an 8km long tungsten-reinforced depleted uranium shell 14m thick. The only question is, would there be enough of the snakebot left to constitute any kind of threat?

Comment: I must say I had no previous idea about the snakebot, however, the fireball of the 50mt Tsar bomb was already 8km in diameter. Surface temperatures of the fireball are around 8000K.  More than twice the tungsten melting point. The inside is obviously much hotter. That's one. OP wants 6 of them. and then roughly 300 more nukes. I'm sorry, there will be nothing left.

Comment: The 'depleted uranium' shell of your snakebot will happily produce lots of yield itself as it soaks up fast neutrons from all the nearby detonations.

Comment: Depleted uranium (U-238) is the precursor of Plutonium-239. After the first 10 nukes, any bits of armor that remain are more of a threat than a help. But this metal armor will be in seawater, and it's going to be quite hot. Melting is a local problem. A bit further away, it will violently react with the salt seawater. It will literally dissolve. This answer is correct - you're going to find a lot of dissolved heavy metals.

Comment: Thinking about it, I am curious how much water would straight up be vaporized using that amount of nukes, and what would happen with that cloud highly radioactive steam once it reaches the surface.

Comment: I recall in the documentary "Independence Day" they nuked an alien spaceship and it remained intact, presumably due to some kind of electromagnetic shielding.  So I wouldn't assume zero changes of survival.

Comment: Using the equation/approximation from https://what-if.xkcd.com/15/ I get ~1.6km for the radius of the initial bubble for exploding the Tsar bomba in 5km of water. (It then implodes and bounces a few times.)

Comment: @Michael that's the problem with nuclear weapon depictions in movies. From all the other unrealististic stuff happening, that was definitely in the top 3.

Answer (score 4):

### Probably very dangerous

The example of nuclear fuel rods in a storage pool has been raised - but nuclear fuel rods are **self-contained**.  They don't leak radioactivity into the water.

[Operation Wigwam](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/70-years-ago-the-us-military-set-off-a-nuke-underwater-and-it-went-very-badly) seems like a reasonable comparison, with only minor contamination of personnel in heavily shielded ships 5 km downwind of the blast site 2000 feet below the surface.  Nonetheless, it is *also* an incomplete analogy, because the nuclear blast had to propel its own radiation all the way to the surface.

In your case, you are setting off a nuclear bomb, blasting the fallout into a wide sphere of superheated water that starts heading off to the surface.  Then you propel that with *another* blast beneath it, and another, and another, all churning up and mixing seafloor sediment and nuclear material, and creating a plume of hot water pulses moving in a train toward the surface.

You can *get* the crew to go down and check, by telling them the reactor pond story and gimmicking their Geiger counters, and the shielding of the sub should help them get some distance down, but make sure they hurry to send that data up a communications link!

Comment: This is rather what I was thinking when I wrote this question.